# Error 324 EMPTY_RESPONSE while echo file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make something like ftp. I have a home made server with aplication set on wamp. 
And i don't want to keep all my files in wamp folder so i also acces local files from this application.

Already read a lot of staff that i can't do this and no browser let me do something like this. But I managed it somehow.

This is the code i use to download files:

```
 function getFile($name,$path) {
    if(file_exists($path.$name)) {
        $name = urldecode($name);
        $fsize = filesize($path.$name); 

        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
        header("Content-type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-length: ".$fsize);

        echo file_get_contents($path.$name);
    }
```

And it works for a small files no matter what extension they've got but i also have to download some .exe files over 200Mb.

i have already set memory_limit in php.ini couse this was the reason of first troubles i've got but now i get the ERROR:324.

Any ideas how to get over it?

Comment: where it saids `file_put_contents` in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents in first read file in memory and then return it. 
For file size of 200MB it need more than 200MB memory for one script.

For fix it you should read file by blocks and output it.

For example

```
$fp = fopen($path.$name, "rb");
if ($fp) {
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $str = fread($fp, 1024);
        echo $str;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but you forget about:

   ob_flush();
   flush();

Comment: If you want then you can add it. But this code just for change call of file_get_contents